# HttpWebRequest is not sending Headers

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest, user-agent

I'm trying to simulate POST web request with HttpWebRequest class:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<my url>));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
```

I need to set cookies for request. I tried tho ways:

```
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, GetGlobalCookies(<cookies url>));

 [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);
    const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

    public static string GetGlobalCookies(string uri)
    {
        uint datasize = 1024;
        StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)datasize);
        if (InternetGetCookieEx(uri, null, cookieData, ref datasize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero)
            && cookieData.Length > 0) {
            return cookieData.ToString(); //.Replace(';', ',');
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(<my url>), GetGlobalCookies(<cookies-url>).Replace(';', ','));
```

GetGlobalCookies() returns correct string with cookies i need. But after running requset.GetResponse() my request in fiddler looks like this:

```
POST <my url> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: <my host>
Content-Length: 3
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

i=1
```

if i change Method to GET then cookies are correcyly sent, but still no User-Agent:

```
GET <my url> HTTP/1.1
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=uajwt1ybpde4hudwwizuq2ld
Host: <my host>
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Why HttpWebRequest is not sending Cookie and User-Agent headers?

Answer (score 11):

OK, figured it out myself. HttpWebRequest constructs request body when you call GetRequestStream(), so you have to set all required headers before calling GetRequestStream(), otherwise they won't be sent.

Comment: That should be definitely written in MS documentation in bold letters. I had a nice day today to figure this fact out (very important Referer header was lost and I did not know why). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class lists steps needed to do in right order, but they must write somewhere in docs this frightening fact: <strong>don't call GetRequestStream() before you set all headers</strong>.

Comment: They made setters specifically for common headers (like Content-Type). You can't set the Content-Type header manually; it won't let you. By doing that, they're saying "we'll handle the Content-Type header for you". Then they blow it by *not setting the Content-Type header*. WTH MS? Either let the developer have the control and the responsibility, or do it for them. This halfway solution pleases no one.  The funny thing is they could have just fixed this. It would only be a breaking change for seriously sloppy code, but they haven't and never will.